# Extract item to item similarity matrix with items' labels

Tags: python

I am using surpriselib library for developing a recommendation engine. It works fine until I tried to extract the item-to-item similarity matrix. Cannot figure out how to add the item labels to it.

What I did:

```
model = KNNWithMeans(k=50, sim_options={'name': pearson, 'user_based': False})
modelo.fit(trainset)
simMatrix = model.compute_similarities()
simMatrix
```

I get this:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.08177423,  0.16506657,  0.        ,  0.07095183,
         0.        ,  0.16260141,  0.08899602,  0.12791694,  0.14374635,
         0.12387712,  0.08574711,  0.16064556,  0.10886727,  0.11882591,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.0946621 ,  0.08517003,  0.15457955,
         0.35675303,  0.        ],
       [ 0.08177423,  1.        ,  0.14978329,  0.        ,  0.07792472,
         0.        ,  0.09436376,  0.10115619,  0.06221614,  0.08744667,
         0.10569248,  0.05256089,  0.01394038,  0.09698251,  0.08596502,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09501267,  0.06804942,  0.18688154,
        -0.15037792,  0.49123398],
       [ 0.16506657,  0.14978329,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.12715413,
         0.        ,  0.11433637,  0.09612114,  0.14094264,  0.13035102,
         0.15065346,  0.07547122,  0.11895713,  0.15634379,  0.08383008,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.08441121,  0.06029899,  0.21006766,
        -0.14641959,  0.35512133],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
```

And I cannot figure out how to add the items' labels to this matrix.